# Tableview lifecycle

Tags: ios, header, tableview, lifecycle, sections

I have a UITableView that I am trying crate with a few sections. I know how to create them and have others working perfectly on my app but this one wont load past `numberSectionsInTableview`.

I have tried adding break points to see where the unrecognized selector error i keep getting is coming into play but can't figure it out. I have commented all of my custom code out so it is back to the boilerplate `UITableView`

My question is then, what is the lifecycle of a `UITableView` and why won't mine load past `numberOfSectionsInTableview` even when I return a simple number. It won't even get to my breakpoint at `numberOfRowsInSection`

Answer:
The `TitleForHeaderInSection` is set immediately after `NumberOfSectionsInTableView`

Comment: Have you set the delegate properly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the delegate and the datasource of the table view?

Something like:

```
myTableView.datasource = self;
myTableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yup, I'm using storyboard and it is all linked correctly. I had it working at one point but just implemented core data. No major changes to this tableview code though.

Comment: Are you having any warnings? Double checked that everuthing is linked correctly. If the delegate is correctly set to your class, it should work 100% sure

Comment: I'm pretty sure i have it set correctly. I just made a new tableview class to try linking it and it works fine (I'm going to try adding my custom code there and hopefully find my problem). Even tried taking out all of my delegate protocols. Sorry I can't post code right now. For reference though does the tableview simply load the number of sections and then the number of rows for section or is there another step in there?

Comment: No, it should be straight, no other steps. Are there other methods in the delegate working?

Comment: Figured it out! There is an extra step in there (if you implement it). After setting number of sections the initialization then jumps to title for header in section. That's where my error was coming from.